# How to take thread dump with jProfiler in offline mode

Tags: jprofiler

I am working with a java program where I am doing profiling using jProfiler. The profiling is done in offline mode.

Once the application is profiled , I am viewing the metrics in jProfiler UI. I can see the method statistics. But i am not able to get the thread dumps. Is there any way to configure the config.xml file to get thread dumps using ofline jprofiler mode.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your session configuration, you have to add a trigger with a "Trigger thread dump" action.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ingo, Thanks for the tip. But where will the thread dump be saved? I am  having trigger for thread dump and also for method statistics. I can save the data for method stats as a .jps file but what about thread dump? Another question is if I can open the thread dump in jProfiler UI just like as in method stats?

Comment: The thread dumps will also be in the .jps file together will all other recorded data.